# Player Levelling function not working how I would like

Tags: javascript

I am creating a very simple text based RPG to test my skills. I am a beginner when it comes to JS and I am using this to learn and hone my existing skills so please bear with me if this seems really basic.

Effectively, I created a function that checks to see if the players current EXP is equal to or greater than the players required EXP. It works great in that it actually levels my player up and gives skill points etc.

Here is the function:

```
    function getExp(amt) {
      player.currentExp += amt;
      if (player.currentExp >= player.reqExp) {
        player.level ++;
        player.reqExp = (player.level * 100) + ((player.level * 10) * 4);
        player.currentExp = 0;
        player.points += 5;
      }
    }
```

Say for example that your required EXP is 100 and you receive 120 EXP points. Instead of adding 20 EXP to the next level, it will always reset to 0. I understand that I have set it to do this, but I am wondering how I could get round this. I would still like the EXP bar to empty and start again from 0 (+ the extra EXP that carried over from the previous level).

I am using HTML progress bars for HP, MP and EXP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A function starting with *get* should return something. May rename it to *set/increase/add*?

Comment: What is your question, do you just want to carry the remaining points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do to fix problems like these is work your logic again *from the start*. The code above levels up the player and the resets the bar. You are not checking if the EXP your player gains is greater or equal to the required amount separately.
Instead what you should do is this:

```
function getExp(amt) {
  player.currentExp += amt;
  if (player.currentExp == player.reqExp) { //the amount gained is equal to the required
    player.level ++;
    player.reqExp = (player.level * 100) + ((player.level * 10) * 4);
    player.currentExp = 0;
    player.points += 5;
  } else if (player.currentExp > player.reqExp){//the amount gained is greater than the required one
    //calculate the extra EXP gained
    var extra = player.currentExp - player.reqExp;
    player.level ++;
    player.reqExp = (player.level * 100) + ((player.level * 10) * 4);
    player.currentExp = extra;
    player.points += 5;
}
```

A friendly note: this logic needs a lot more work, for example, what if the player gains exp equal to two levels?

Answer (score 0):

If the level is proportional to the required amount its easy:

```
 player.level += Math.floor(player.currentExp/100);
 player.currentExp=player.currentExp%100;
```

If you want a continual increasing required exp, may do this:

```
 player.requiredExp=100;

 function getExp(val){
  player.currentExp+=val;
  while(player.currentExp>=player.requiredExp){
    player.requiredExp=player.requiredExp+100;//or some other algorithm
    player.level++;
    player.currentExp-=player.requiredExp;
  }
 }
```

And a function referring to player, should be part of the player object, and your function name is not wisely chosen ( other people may want to use your code somewhen), so the whole thing how i would write it:

```
var player={
  level:0,
  _exp:0,
  set exp(value){
    this._exp+=value;
    this.level += Math.floor(this._exp/100);
    this._exp=this._exp%100;
  },
  get exp(){ return this._exp}
};
```

So you can easily do:

```
player.exp+=500;
```

http://jsbin.com/rogolapume/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to iterate through your level required experience and just substract the amount of exp need for said level on each loop. At some point you will reach a level which required experience is higher than your experience, at that point return the level.

```js
var exp = document.querySelector(".exp");
var levelDOM = document.querySelector(".currentLevel");
exp.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
 var newValue = getExp(exp.value);
  levelDOM.innerHTML = newValue;
  console.log(newValue)
});

var level = [100, 200, 300, 600, 700, 800, 1000];


function getExp(exp) {
 for(var i = 0; i < level.length; i ++) {
   if(exp > level[i]) {
     exp -= level[i];
    } else {
     return i + 1;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="exp" />
Current Level : <span class="currentLevel"></span>
```